# Occupied Position in Tic-Tac-Toe Game [C]

Tags: c

One question about this code: if the choice the player picks is already taken, how do I make him/her choose again?

If I compile the code now, it will change the the position for the one the user chose, and this can't happen.

Obs: the "drawing" of the tic-tac-toe game should appear before this (`"\nInform your choice (1-9): "`)

This is the code:

```
char mat[9];

int main(void)
{
  int i,jogada,casa,jogo=0;

  for(i=0; i<= 9; i++) 
    mat[i] = ' ';

 do{
  printf("\n");
  printf("\t|\t|\n");
  printf("\t|\t|\n");
  printf("%c\t|%c\t|%c\n",mat[1],mat[2],mat[3]);
  printf("--------|-------|-------\n");
  printf("\t|\t|\n");
  printf("%c\t|%c\t|%c\n",mat[4],mat[5],mat[6]);
  printf("--------|-------|-------\n");
  printf("\t|\t|\n");
  printf("\t|\t|\n");
  printf("%c\t|%c\t|%c\n\n",mat[7],mat[8],mat[9]);
  printf("\nJOGADOR X ");
  printf("\nInforme uma posicao livre (1-9): ");
  scanf("%d",&casa);
  }while((casa>=1)&&(casa<=9));

  if((casa>=1)&&(casa<=9))
  {

  if(mat[casa] == 'X' || mat[casa] == 'O')
     printf(" ");
  else     
     mat[casa] = 'X';

  }      
  printf("\n");
  printf("\t|\t|\n");
  printf("\t|\t|\n");
  printf("%c\t|%c\t|%c\n",mat[1],mat[2],mat[3]);
  printf("--------|-------|-------\n");
  printf("\t|\t|\n");
  printf("%c\t|%c\t|%c\n",mat[4],mat[5],mat[6]);
  printf("--------|-------|-------\n");
  printf("\t|\t|\n");
  printf("\t|\t|\n");
  printf("%c\t|%c\t|%c\n\n",mat[7],mat[8],mat[9]);



  if(mat[1] != ' ' && mat[1] == mat[2] && mat[2] == mat[3]) {
              jogo++;
              printf("X Ganhou!\n"); 
              break;  }
       else if(mat[4] != ' ' && mat[4] == mat[5] && mat[5] == mat[6]) {
              printf("X Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++;
              break; }
       else if(mat[7] != ' ' && mat[7] == mat[8] && mat[8] == mat[9]) {
              printf("X Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++;
                break; }
       else if(mat[1] != ' ' && mat[1] == mat[4] && mat[4] == mat[7]) {
              printf("X Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++; 
                break;}
       else if(mat[2] != ' ' && mat[2] == mat[5] && mat[5] == mat[8]) {
              printf("X Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++;
                break; }
       else if(mat[3] != ' ' && mat[3] == mat[6] && mat[6] == mat[9]) {
              printf("X Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++;
                break; }
       else if(mat[1] != ' ' && mat[1] == mat[5] && mat[5] == mat[9]){ 
               printf("X Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++; 
                break;}
       else if(mat[7] != ' ' && mat[7] == mat[5] && mat[5] == mat[3]) { 
               printf("X Ganhou!\n"); 
              jogo++;
                break; }
       else if((mat[1] != ' ') && (mat[2] != ' ') && (mat[3] != ' ') && (mat[4] != ' ') && (mat[5] != ' ') && (mat[6] != ' ') && (mat[7] != ' ') && (mat[8] != ' ') && (mat[9] = ' ')){
                printf("Velha!\n");
                jogo++;
                break;
                }

     printf("\nJOGADOR O ");
     printf("\nInforme uma posicao livre (1-9): ");
     scanf("%d",&casa);
     if((casa>=1)&&(casa<=9))
     {

     if(mat[casa] == 'X' || mat[casa] == 'O')
     ;
     else     
        mat[casa] = 'O';

     }            
     printf("\n");
     printf("\t|\t|\n");
     printf("\t|\t|\n");
     printf("%c\t|%c\t|%c\n",mat[1],mat[2],mat[3]);
     printf("--------|-------|-------\n");
     printf("\t|\t|\n");
     printf("%c\t|%c\t|%c\n",mat[4],mat[5],mat[6]);
     printf("--------|-------|-------\n");
     printf("\t|\t|\n");
     printf("\t|\t|\n");
     printf("%c\t|%c\t|%c\n\n",mat[7],mat[8],mat[9]);


       if(mat[1] != ' ' && mat[1] == mat[2] && mat[2] == mat[3]) {
              printf("O Ganhou!\n");  
              jogo++;
                break; }
       else if(mat[4] != ' ' && mat[4] == mat[5] && mat[5] == mat[6]) {
              printf("O Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++;
                break; }
       else if(mat[7] != ' ' && mat[7] == mat[8] && mat[8] == mat[9]) {
              printf("O Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++;
                break; }
       else if(mat[1] != ' ' && mat[1] == mat[4] && mat[4] == mat[7]) {
              printf("O Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++;
                break; }
       else if(mat[2] != ' ' && mat[2] == mat[5] && mat[5] == mat[8]) {
              printf("O Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++; 
                break;}
       else if(mat[3] != ' ' && mat[3] == mat[6] && mat[6] == mat[9]) {
              printf("O Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++;
                break; }
       else if(mat[1] != ' ' && mat[1] == mat[5] && mat[5] == mat[9]){ 
               printf("O Ganhou!\n");
              jogo++; 
                break;}
       else if(mat[7] != ' ' && mat[7] == mat[5] && mat[5] == mat[3]) { 
               printf("O Ganhou!\n"); 
              jogo++;
                break; }
      else if((mat[1] != ' ') && (mat[2] != ' ') && (mat[3] != ' ') && (mat[4] != ' ') && (mat[5] != ' ') && (mat[6] != ' ') && (mat[7] != ' ') && (mat[8] != ' ') && (mat[9] = ' ')){
                printf("Velha!\n");
                jogo++;
                break;
                }

}

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. What have you tried so far, and what happened?

Comment: this code shouldn't do anything with the users input as casa is never used except in scanf

Comment: I had posted the wrong code , sorry =/. The homework is to do the tic-tactoe game, the only thing i can't do is this part.

Comment: Note that you may not use `mat[9]` as `mat` has length 9, so the last element would be `mat[8]`. (And start with `mat[0]`!)

Comment: But i´m not using the mat[0] position , that won't affect the code.

Answer (score 0):

**If the choice the player picks is already taken, how do I make him/her choose again?**

Change your `scanf()` in 2 locations  (X and O)

```
do {
  printf("\nInforme uma posicao livre (1-9): ");
  scanf("%d",&casa);
} while( (casa<1) || (casa>9) || (mat[casa] != ' ') );
```

---

You do have a *bigger* problem.

Change `char mat[9]` to `char mat[10]`.  You are indexing your `mat[]` from 1 to 9 throughout your code.  But `char mat[9]` only allows mat[0] to mat[8].  The quick fix is to make mat[] 1 char longer and not use mat[0].  Leave `for(i=0; i<= 9; i++)` as is.

- OR -

A proper fix would be to keep `char mat[9]` and change all the many mat[i] references to mat[i-1].  e.g. mat[5] becomes mat[4].  Change to `for(i=0; i < 9; i++)`.

---